# Using shiny to produce a datatable that is downloadable and uses dplyr functions

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to create a shiny app that that takes various inputs and creates an output table that has columns that record the user inputs and calculates a cost field based on user inputs. I have been successful in creating the data table with the user inputs, but I can't get the field that calculates something new based on the input data.

```
data <- structure(list(product = c("Cars", "Trucks", "Buses", "Cars", 
"Trucks", "Buses"), offshore = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


               library(shiny)
                library(DT)
                library(data.table)
                library(lubridate)
                library(tidyverse)


                mydata = data.frame(Product=NA,
                                    Start_date = NA,
                                    End_date = NA,
                                    On_shore_cost = NA,
                                    Off_shore_cost = NA,
                                    Cost = NA)
             ui <- fluidPage(
              wellPanel(
               flowLayout(
                 selectInput("select", "Product", 
                                      choices = list("Cars"  = 1,
                                                     "Trucks" = 2,
                                                     "Buses" = 3), selected = 1),   
                 dateInput("sdate", "Start date"),
                 dateInput("edate", "End date"),
                 numericInput("onshore","On-Shore Cost",1),
                 numericInput("offshore","Off-Shore Cost",1)
                 actionButton("action","Blast Off")),
                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")),
                 dataTableOutput("table")


        )
```

The field I am trying to create is the "Cost =" field. I use a dplyr expression to manipulate the data. I can't seem to get this to work. As a bonus, once the a user builds the table they want, I would like for them to be able to download it. I haven't spent much time on the download piece yet. Could you help me to figure out how to populate the "Cost" field of the data table?

```
    # Define server logic 
    server <- function(input, output) {

     output$table <- renderDataTable( df())

     df <-  eventReactive(input$action,{
      if(input$select!="" && !is.null(input$onshore)  && input$action>0){
       newrow = data.table(Product = input$select, 
                   Start_date = as.character(input$sdate),
                   End_date = as.character(input$edate),
                   On_shore_cost =input$onshore,
                   Off_shore_cost = input$offshore,


#########This is the trouble spot, I am trying to generate this field
                   Cost = renderText({data %>% filter(product == input$select) %>% 
    mutate(pc_cost= ifelse(offshore == 0 , input$onshore,input$offshore)) %>%
          summarise(total = sum(pc_cost)) %>% pull()}) )


     mydata <<- rbind(mydata, newrow)


      }
      mydata
     }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)  
    }


    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you edit to make this minimum reproducible example (cut extraneous data and UI elements, and `dput` a small data frame of your data), so people here can cut and paste it into their own R session and launch a local shiny app to reproduce the issue? Also helpful to write comments in the code to remind people where the problem is happening. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there were a few mistakes in your code. But are you looking for something like that? One of the problems I think was the numbers you assigned to the products. It could not filter correctly.

```
 ui <- fluidPage(
              wellPanel(
               flowLayout(
                 selectInput("select", "Product", 
                                      choices = list("Cars",
                                                     "Trucks",
                                                     "Buses"), selected = "Cars"),   
                 dateInput("sdate", "Start date"),
                 dateInput("edate", "End date"),
                 numericInput("onshore","On-Shore Cost",1),
                 numericInput("offshore","Off-Shore Cost",1),
                 actionButton("action","Blast Off")),
                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")),
                 dataTableOutput("table")


        )

server <- function(input, output) {

  #observeEvent(input$action,{
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable( df())

 # })


  df <-  eventReactive(input$action,{
   # if(input$select!="" && !is.null(input$onshore)  && input$action>0){
      newrow = data.frame(Product = input$select, 
                          Start_date = as.character(input$sdate),
                          End_date = as.character(input$edate),
                          On_shore_cost =input$onshore,
                          Off_shore_cost = input$offshore)


                          #########This is the trouble spot, I am trying to generate this field
      Cost = data %>% dplyr::filter(as.factor(product) %in% c(paste(as.factor(input$select))))  %>% 
        mutate(pc_cost= ifelse(as.numeric(offshore) == 0, as.numeric(input$onshore), as.numeric(input$offshore))) %>%
        summarise(total = sum(pc_cost)) %>% pull()


      mydata <<- cbind(Cost, newrow)
      mydata

  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That handled the biggest issue. I added another rbind so it would add to the data set. Thank you for your time!